# AJAX post to alter a mongodb array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, mongodb, post

Hey so I have a table which is generated from a Mongodb collection 'posts'. The table lists a day, time and reward for users and then presents a 'choose' button. When the choose button is clicked I want to change the user array for that particular post in the database and add the id of the user that clicked the post.

Hopefully I have explained the problem clearly enough, thanks for any help or advise. I believe the problem is in my choosePost function in my shifts.js but I'm new to AJAX calls and cant seem to figure it out.

This is my HTML table

```
div style="margin:0 -16px" class="row-padding" id="postsToChoose">
                 <table>
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><h1> Day  </h1></th>
                            <th><h1> Time </h1></th>
                            <th><h1> Reward </h1></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
            </div>
```

My shift.js

```
var studentListData = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
popPostTable();
$('#postsToChoose table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkChoosePost', choosePost);
});

function popPostTable() {
var tableContent = ''; 
$.getJSON( '/postsToChoose', function( data ) {
    $.each(data, function(){
        studentListData = data;
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.dayOfTheWeek + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.shiftTime + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.reward + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkChoosePost" rel="' + this._id + '">choose</a></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#postsToChoose table tbody').html(tableContent);
 });
};

function choosePost(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to choose this shift?');
if (confirmation === true) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/choosePost/' + $(this).attr('rel')
    }).done(function( response ) {
        if (response.msg === '') {
        }
        else {
            alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
        }
        popPostTable();
    });
}
else {
    return false;
}
};
```

and my relevant index.js

```
    router.get('/postsToChoose', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('posts').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        console.log("check for posts"+items);
        res.json(items);
    });
    });
    router.post('/choosePost/:id', function(req, res) { 
    var db = req.db;
    var chosenPost = req.params.id;  
    var userID = req.user._id;
    console.log("USERID: "+ userID);
    console.log("The is the chosen post"+ chosenPost);
    db.collection('posts').update(
        { _id : chosenPost }, //posts._id params.id
        { $set : { 
            "user":userID
        } 
        });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'Post created');
    res.redirect('/hub');
});
```

The post model is as follows

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b8215e82ea04412d433a48"),
    "user" : [ 
    "1223344vew4683928b",  
    "9484794782bkc00980"
    ],
    "location" : "Dublin",
    "reward" : 300,
    "company" : "Apple",
    "shiftTime" : "day",
    "dayOfTheWeek" : "4",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Use `{ $push: { 
            "user":userID
        }` to alter array.

Comment: @Veeram thanks for the tip, that makes a lot of sense however still nothing is getting pushed to the user array